# RemoveClass from every element that's not (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my proto, i have a controller with three buttons controlling three divs. each button is set to a different jQuery selector, all, eq, even.

everything seems to work well but when i transition from one toggled-on option to another, the previous selection is carried through to the next one instead of reseting completely from scratch. if i add a function to reset all the divs, my divs don't toggle.

**i'm wondering if there's a way to removeClass from every element except the element that was selected.**

appreciate any help!

code below:
proto here: http://jsfiddle.net/terra823/L63e3mjL/4/

```
function clearAll() {
    $('#controller .button').removeClass('theSelected');
}



$('#one').on('click', function () {
    clearAll();
    $('.littleDiv*').toggleClass('theHighlighted');
    $(this).toggleClass('theSelected');
});


$('#two').on('click', function () {
    clearAll();
    $('.littleDiv:eq(1)').toggleClass('theHighlighted');
    $(this).toggleClass('theSelected');
});


$('#three').on('click', function () {
    clearAll();
    $('.littleDiv:even').toggleClass('theHighlighted');
    $(this).toggleClass('theSelected');
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you problem is. Current behavior looks fine: each div is toggled from whatever state it has *at the moment*. If you add `$(".littleDiv").removeClass("theHighlighted");` to the `clearAll`, then each div is toggled from clear state. What is not working the way you want?

Comment: moving from option to option should reset as if no div were selected. if i toggle option one on and then move to option two, option two starts with option one already toggled-on instead of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling toggleClass but not removing the class first. So in some cases it's going to remove the class when it should add the class. Toggle is going to add the class when it doesn't have it, and remove it when it does. By making sure the class is removed first it's going to add it as expected. At this point, though, toggleClass should probably be replaced with addClass so it's more readable.

Here's a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/L63e3mjL/9/

```
function clearAll() {
    $('#controller .button').removeClass('theSelected');
    $('.theHighlighted').removeClass('theHighlighted');
}
```

Edit with new requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/L63e3mjL/19/

I'm going to find a more elequint way to do this, but for now I've added a variable to keep track of which button is clicked. Using that we can clear when we're coming from a different button, but if we're clicking the same button we dont clear and allow toggleClass to toggle the divs.

Edit2: Just for fun I cleaned it up into one function. http://jsfiddle.net/L63e3mjL/21/

```
var current;
var buttons = $('.button');

buttons.click(function(e){
    var button =  $(this);
    var index = button.index();
    var divs;

    if(current != index) clearAll();
    current = index;

    if(index == 0) divs = $('.littleDiv*');
    else if(index == 1) divs = $('.littleDiv:eq(1)');
    else if(index == 2) divs = $('.littleDiv:even');

    divs.toggleClass('theHighlighted'); 
    button.addClass('theSelected');
});
```

Comment: hey kolby, i tried this but i noticed doing this kills the toggle functionality of the three buttons, which also happens in your example.

Comment: oh ya I see what you mean, 1 second I'll fix it up

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L63e3mjL/10/)

```
function clearAll() {
    $('#controller .button').removeClass('theSelected');
}



$('#one').on('click', function () {
    clearAll();
    $('.littleDiv').removeClass('theHighlighted').eq(0).addClass('theHighlighted');
    $(this).addClass('theSelected');
});


$('#two').on('click', function () {
    clearAll();
    $('.littleDiv').removeClass('theHighlighted').eq(1).addClass('theHighlighted');
    $(this).addClass('theSelected');
});


$('#three').on('click', function () {
    clearAll();
    $('.littleDiv').removeClass('theHighlighted').eq(2).addClass('theHighlighted');
    $(this).addClass('theSelected');
});
```

Comment: i need to use the specific jQuery selectors mentioned in the original post. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

just needed to beef up the toogleClass function. would be great if there was a more elegant way to do this.

```
 $("#one").click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('theHighlighted');
 if($("#one").hasClass('theHighlighted')){
     $(this).removeClass('theHighlighted');
  }
 $(this).toggleClass('theSelected');
 if($("#one").hasClass('theSelected')){
     $(this).removeClass('theSelected');
  }

 })
```